# Change multiple groups of radio buttons with a button

Tags: php, forms

I'm in need of a button to change multiple groups of radio buttons to the same value. Does anybody have a solution on how to achieve this?

For example I have 5 groups of 2 radio buttons and it just so happens they are going to be the same answer. Rather than my user pressing 5 separate radios buttons, I'd like them to have a short cut as such. I'm using an array form like this below if it makes a difference? Free to use any language.

```
<li>
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td><label class="status"><input type="radio" name="status[1]" value="Untested" /><img src="images/ButtonUnproven.png"></label></td>
            <td><label class="status"><input type="radio" name="status[1]" value="Roped" /><img src="images/ButtonGreen.png"></label></td>
            <td><label class="status"><input type="radio" name="status[1]" value="Sub-ducted" /><img src="images/ButtonBlue.png"></label></td>
            <td><label class="status"><input type="radio" name="status[1]" value="Cabled" /><img src="images/ButtonRed.png"></label></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
    <li>
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td><label class="status"><input type="radio" name="status[1]" value="Stop" /><img src="images/ButtonStop.png"></label></td>
            <td><label class="status"><input type="radio" name="status[1]" value="Desilt" /><img src="images/ButtonDesilt.png"></label></td>
            <td><label class="status"><input type="radio" name="status1[]" value="Overlay" /><img src="images/ButtonOverlay.png"></label></td>
            <td><label class="status"><input type="radio" name="tma[1]" value="No" /><img src="images/ButtonNoTM.png"></label></td>
            <td><label class="status"><input type="radio" name="tma[1]" value="Yes" /><img src="images/ButtonTM.png"></label></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li><li>
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td><label class="status"><input type="radio" name="status[2]" value="Untested" /><img src="images/ButtonUnproven.png"></label></td>
            <td><label class="status"><input type="radio" name="status[2]" value="Roped" /><img src="images/ButtonGreen.png"></label></td>
            <td><label class="status"><input type="radio" name="status[2]" value="Sub-ducted" /><img src="images/ButtonBlue.png"></label></td>
            <td><label class="status"><input type="radio" name="status[2]" value="Cabled" /><img src="images/ButtonRed.png"></label></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
    <li>
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td><label class="status"><input type="radio" name="status[2]" value="Stop" /><img src="images/ButtonStop.png"></label></td>
            <td><label class="status"><input type="radio" name="status[2]" value="Desilt" /><img src="images/ButtonDesilt.png"></label></td>
            <td><label class="status"><input type="radio" name="status[2]" value="Overlay" /><img src="images/ButtonOverlay.png"></label></td>
            <td><label class="status"><input type="radio" name="tma[2]" value="No" /><img src="images/ButtonNoTM.png"></label></td>
            <td><label class="status"><input type="radio" name="tma[2]" value="Yes" /><img src="images/ButtonTM.png"></label></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xxy27/6/) example of what I'm working with. Images are missing as they are on my local server, but you will get the gist.

Comment: Can you post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? It simplifies things.

Comment: Will knock one up now

Comment: Is there supposed to be any groups? They seem to select and deselect in random order.

Comment: I've uploaded the images, that should give you a better idea what I mean. JSFiddle link updated.

Comment: Apparently, you need a JS solution, not a PHP one? if PHP, it's trivial to include a form with a single button calling the php form with the right parameter to trigger the behaviour you are looking for (namely check the radio buttons with the same value in each menu). In JS, you need to add a button attached to a js function doing that very action. It should be straightforward with jquery to select the radio items you want (don't forget to unselect the other ones first).

Comment: hint : http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: I didn't think it would be possible without JS. I couldn't write a line of JS if I tried to be honest

Comment: That seems just the ticket. I'll have a Google and find out how to fire a script from button. Thanks for the help

Comment: What does the "shortcut" will do?

Comment: jquery? `$('input[type=radio]').val('foo')`?

Comment: It just sets all buttons to green for example rather than the user pressing them individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#AllRoped').click(function () {
    $("input[value=Roped]").prop('checked', true);
});
})
</script>
```

HTML

```
<button id="AllRoped" type="button">All Roped</button>
```

This is what I got in the end and works as intended. Replace "Roped" with any value you need.